# F# test if the result is Some(any)

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fscheck

I need to check whether my validation function returns `some`thing when fails or `none`. If it returns `Some<string>`, there is a validation error, otherwise it's valid and the function returns `None`.
This is my attempt , but it's not refactoring safe:

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[| typeof<Strings.WithLenFrom1To100> |])>]
    let ``lengthValidator should return some error when the string's length is longer than expected``(str:string)=
        let maxValidLen = str.Length-1
        let actual = lengthValidator maxValidLen str

        let expected = Some(sprintf "Maximum string length is %i but %s contains %i characters" maxValidLen str str.Length)
        //How can I say **let expected = Some(anything) **instead

        test <@actual = expected@>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test <@ actual.IsSome @>
```

Comment: Perfect! How can I do it for my custom `Discriminated Union`s ?

Comment: `match myDu with MyCase _ -> true | _ -> false`